# Send PHP errors back to index

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, security

So I have an `index.php` and a `r.php`. `R.php` is the registration part. And `index.php` is the actual form. My question is how can I have errors from `r.php` be send back to `index.php` if they exist. So instead of displaying errors on `r.php` I want them on `index.php` and prevent the form from advancing.

Here's the `index.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="r.php">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Its all very simple. Now here's `r.php`

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];

if ($name < 3){
    //display error
}
else {
    //proceed
}
?>
```

Should I do this with JS? Or this there a better way.

Comment: The normal way is to have r.php and index.php be in the same file. This could simplify things

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Pear.... @pce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use sessions:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php echo isset($_SESSION['message']) ? $_SESSION['message'] : ''; ?>
    <form method="post" action="r.php">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

---

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['message']);
$name = $_POST['name'];

if ($name < 3){  // you probably want strlen($name) < 3
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'error';
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}
else {
    //proceed
}
?>
```

Other than sessions you could redirect back with a query string and use that:

```
header('Location: index.php?message=' . urlencode('some kind of error');
```

Then:

```
<?php echo isset($_GET['message']) ? $_GET['message'] : ''; ?>
```

Comment: It all seems to be good. But when I go back after the error is still there. I've tried using `unset($_SESSION['message']);` after `exit;` but it isn't working. Any ideas where I should stick it?

Comment: One shouldn't echo $_GET Variables without filtering, at least use htmlspecialchars or htmlentities, because this is vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: I am aware of SQL injections and XSS. I'll make sure to clean that up after I get an understanding of this. @pce

Comment: Just an example.  I edited with a `unset($_SESSION['message']);`

Comment: Still not unsetting. I only want them to show once. Like after the user refreshes the page after getting the messages I don't want them there. Otherwise nice answer.

Comment: Sure it's not the `if ($name < 3){` causing probs?  `'user302975' < 3 === true`

Comment: For some reason when i do `$name === 3` and enter a 3 character string it doesn't run...

Comment: string `'3'` from POST is NOT === integer `3`.

Comment: I can confirm that the if/else statement is good. But the session keeps going. If I refresh `index.php`, (the error is here). I still won't go away.

Comment: Refreshing won't clear it unless you `unset()` at the bottom of the form.  Why would a refresh clear it?  It wasn't resubmitted with valid data.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I want to do. Say I get an error. And I refresh that page. I don't want the errors there. So where would I place `unset()`? At the bottom of `r.php` or `index.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Using a single script for this would be easier, just put this all in one file, and check to see if the form has been submitted. If the form has been submitted, you an just include the variables you want straight away.

This is pretty crude, but it gives you an idea of where you can go with this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    // Begin processing form stuff
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    // Initialise error variable
    $error = null;    

    if ($name < 3) {
        // Display error, for example:
        $error = 'Name is less than 3';
    } else {
        // Proceed
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <?php if ( ! empty($error)) { ?>
        <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
    <form method="post" action="r.php">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am aware of this. But I'm trying to do it with 2 files.

Comment: Okay, then you could use a redirect from `r.php` and set some `GET` variables. The only truly reliable way of doing this is having a front controller really.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<?php

  $msg = '';

  if(isset($_GET['e'])
  {
    $msg = "Error! Input not valid.";
  }
?>
    <body>
    <?php
        if($msg!='')
        {
          echo "<font color='red'>".$msg."</font>";
        }
    ?>
     <form method="post" action="r.php">
      <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

Just pass a variable e using GET request to the index page if an error is found.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];

if ($name < 3){
    header("Location: index.php?e=error");
}
else {
    //proceed
}
?>
```

GET request will send the variable e using the URL, and if e is found to be having a value, it means there was an error in r.php

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript for simple form validation. In case you require some security stuff or db stuff, you can use session/cookie or use header function to go back.